# How to specify the path to "package.json" when running npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm

For a new project I am working on, I want to install my node packages in one directory while having my "packages.json" file in another. In other words, I want to have my "node_modules" directory and "packages.json" file in two separate folders. Is there a way to do this? I have looked through the  command documentary, but can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You create a separate `package.json` in every folder where you want `node_modules` in the same folder. That's how NPM works ;)

You can have any number of `package.json` files in your project.

Other than that, you cannot separate `node_modules` from `package.json`, because Node.js uses `package.json` to look for the right modules that you include with `require`. For example, when running `npm update` in that folder, you need both pieces in the same folder.

And that's how NPM and Node.js work happily together ;)